# How to create a similar method in Python like using colon operator (:) to create dataframe in R?

Tags: python, r, pandas

In R, we can create a dataframe like this:

```
name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria")

data.frame(name, "nb"= 3:1)
```

and the output is:

```
   name   nb
1   Jon    3
2  Bill    2
3 Maria    1
```

How can I use the same method in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
l = [["Jon", "Bill", "Maria"], range(3,0,-1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(l).T
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
       0  1
0    Jon  3
1   Bill  2
2  Maria  1
```

Comment: Edited answer is better